# Why is Excel running out of Memory?

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot figure out why my code is erroring out. I ran it with a smaller data set and it had no issues, but when I expanded it to 14k lines it completely shuts down on line 51 saying first "Excel is out of memory" and then "Insert Method of Range Class Failed" . I was anticipating handing it off to someone who might look at the code so it is heavily commented.

The code is supposed to take the raw data and put it into a format for upload into an older system. To do that it needs to add a row above each unique account and mark that row as a Header row (with an H). It also adds some columns.

Any ideas as to why it is throwing errors would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ProgramUpload()

'First we define our worksheet variables
Dim wsRaw As Worksheet
Set wsRaw = Worksheets("Raw Data")
Dim wsW As Worksheet
Set wsW = Worksheets("Program Upload")

wsW.UsedRange.ClearContents

'We need a temporary spreadsheet, so let us create and define it
Sheets.Add.Name = "Temporary"
Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
Set wsTemp = Worksheets("Temporary")

Dim lrRaw As Long
lrRaw = wsRaw.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'We want to copy the raw data from Raw to the Program Upload
wsW.Range("A1:C" & lrRaw).Value = wsRaw.Range("A1:C" & lrRaw).Value

'We need to copy column A into our temporary sheet because we want
'to create a unique list of accounts. I chose column Q to make it
'easier to tell what worksheet we are dealing with.

wsTemp.Range("Q1:Q" & lrRaw).Value = wsRaw.Range("A1:A" & lrRaw).Value

'Remove the duplicates
wsTemp.Range("Q1:Q" & lrRaw).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

'Locate the last row with data in Q
Dim lrQ As Long
lrQ = wsTemp.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Now we want to define our current row on Q
Dim rQ As Long
rQ = 2 'Since we left headers in we want to start at Q2

wsW.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Insert
wsW.Range("A2:A" & lrRaw).Value = "D"
Dim rFind As Long

For rQ = 2 To lrQ
    rFind = wsW.Range("B1:B" & lrRaw + lrQ).Find(What:=wsTemp.Range("Q" & rQ).Value).Row
    wsW.Rows(rFind).EntireRow.Insert   'Error Happens Here! 
    wsW.Rows(rFind).Value = wsW.Rows(rFind + 1).Value 'Sometimes Errors Here As Well! 
    wsW.Range("A" & rFind).Value = "H"
Next rQ

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Temporary").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wsW.Columns("C:F").EntireColumn.Insert

wsW.Range("A1").Value = "Column 1"
wsW.Range("B1").Value = "Column 2"
wsW.Range("C1").Value = "Column 3"
wsW.Range("D1").Value = "Column 4"
wsW.Range("E1").Value = "Column 5"
wsW.Range("F1").Value = "Column 6"
wsW.Range("G1").Value = "Column 7"
wsW.Range("H1").Value = "Column 8"
wsW.Range("I1").Value = "Column 9"

wsW.Range("A:I").Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Is it `32-bit` or `64-bit`?

Comment: @Arod Ponyboy678. 32 bit. We cannot use 64bit.

Comment: So I see a few possible problems in your code. It looks like you might be inserting rows as your `for` loop traverses across the rows - so now, your next row might be the row you inserted! However, if you're sure it worked for smaller datasets, then it's unlikely this is it.

I would try saving your workbook every ~100 iterations? Saving the workbook reduces the amount of stuff Excel has to remember, saving memory. you can use the `Workbook.Save` method

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with test data, but I can see how it's stripping away all rows after 49 or 51.

Comment: @ArodPonyboy678  Added a Save step so that it triggers every step works about 50% of the time sometimes it gets to iteration 200 and then fails, but I don't understand why memory is even an issue with this workbook. The things it is doing are 1. Searching 14K rows for a value, saving the row of that value, inserting a row, value of new row =value of row below. I've run Find on much larger data. This document only has this data in plain text and has no other tabs. No other programs are running to eat up the usable memory.

Comment: @dwirony What do you mean by stripping away? It shouldn't be deleting any rows.....

Comment: Every time you make a change, Excel has to keep track of it. So if you have a lot of unsaved changes, then Excel has to keep track of _all_ of them - otherwise, when you quit, you'll lose them!

So does that mean it made it farther than before?

Comment: @ArodPonyboy678 I closed excel and ran the code and it ran all the way through once (taking a /very/ long time) The next time I ran the code it stopped on rQ 120, then rQ 28, then rQ 3. I restarted Excel again and ran it again and it has been spinning for about 10 minutes now. Not sure if it is going to error or run.

Comment: Are you saving every time? Or are you saving every `n` times?

Comment: @ArodPonyboy678 Saving every time. Whenever I tried bumping the frequency of saves down it crashes on rQ =2 . I tried saving on rQ=2 and then evens and it errored out on rQ=12

Comment: What does your `for` loop look like now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183328/discussion-between-emily-alden-and-arod-ponyboy678).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel doesn't like copying large amounts of data over and over again, because it has to keep that data in memory - in your `For` loop, you *insert an entire row* - Excel rows can extend for quite a long time, so Excel has to keep all of this in memory at the same time.

Instead, I would suggest you only copy over the columns you need. Suppose we have 5 columns; then perhaps your `For` loop could look like this:

```
For rQ = 2 To lrQ 
    rFind = wsW.Range("B1:B" & lrRaw + lrQ).Find(What:=wsRaw.Range("Q" & rQ).Value).Row 
    wsW.Rows(rFind).EntireRow.Insert
    ' Notice we're only copying over 5 columns - not the entire row! 
    wsW.Range(Cells(rFind, 1), Cells(rFind, 5)).Value = wsW.Range(Cells(rFind + 1, 1), Cells(rFind + 1, 5)).Value
    wsW.Range("A" & rFind).Value = "H" 
Next rQ
```